# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable (Python3 with Oracle 19c)

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror, cx-oracle

Python 3.6.3 /
Oracle 19c

The following script runs fine till it hits `upc_id, = cur.fetchone()`. Could someone explain, please what may cause it? If I run the query in database, I get the result back (see below). Is there a way to see exactly what Oracle runs, after variable substitution? I suspect single quotes are not in place for bind variables, but how can I confirm?

```
import datetime
import cx_Oracle
import db

line_item_sku = 'Y35FLPQ_034Y_M'
x = line_item_sku.split("_")

print (x)
print ("Split-list len: "+ str(len(x)))

if len(x) == 3:
    sku_with_dimension = False
elif len(x) == 4:
    sku_with_dimension = True

print ("SKU with dimension: " + str(sku_with_dimension))

style_id = x[0]
color_id = x[1]
size_id = x[2]
if sku_with_dimension:
    dimension_id = x[3]

print ("Style: "+style_id) 
print ("Color: "+color_id) 
print ("Size: "+size_id)

conn = db.connect('Galo')
print ("Connected to: " + conn.version)

cur = conn.cursor()

upc_id = cur.var(str)
print ("Assigned return value")

if sku_with_dimension:
    sql = ("""      
            select upc_id                                                                       
            from sku
            where business_unit_id = '81'
            and style_id = :1
            and color_id = :2
            and identifier_id = 'EA'
            and size_id = :3
            and dimension_id = :4
        """)
    cur.execute(sql,(style_id, color_id, size_id, dimension_id))
else:
    sql = ("""      
            select upc_id                                                                       
            from sku
            where business_unit_id = '81'
            and style_id = :1
            and color_id = :2
            and identifier_id = 'EA'
            and size_id = :3                        
        """)
    cur.execute(sql,(style_id, color_id, size_id))

print ("Determined which query to run")

upc_id, = cur.fetchone()
print (upc_id)

db.disconnect(conn, cur)
```

Here is the output

```
'Y35FLPQ', '034Y', 'M'] 
Split-list len: 3 
SKU with dimension: False 
Style: Y35FLPQ 
Color: 034Y 
Size: M 
Connected to: 19.0.0.0.0 
Assigned return value 
Determined which query to run 
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "c:/Python/code/test.py", line 66, in <module>
    upc_id, = cur.fetchone() 
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

If I run the query in database, I receive a result back:

[image]

Comment: Apparently, `cur.fetchone()` failed and returned `None`.

Comment: Is there a way to find exact query that Oracle runs?

Comment: Do some debugging: does a `select count(*) from sku` in Python return anything (are you connected to the correct DB)?  Do you have any issues with leading/trailing whitespace in data (or CHAR column types?).  You can do some tracing in cx_Oracle, see the [manual](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tracing_sql.html) but if you want to trace the actual data substitution in the statement you need to do that in the DB; Google for 'oracle tracing bind variables'.  In general use named bind variables to avoid potential bind variable ordering issues (but this isn't a cause here).

Comment: Thanks Christopher, I've done desc sku; and had to pad all returned values in Python to match table definition like this: cur.execute(sql,(style_id.ljust(14,' '), color_id.ljust(6,' '), size_id.ljust(5,' '))) It worked then.